# Div with table cell only works 1 time

Tags: html, css

When I made a div with display:table-cell; it shows like the first picture. (this is what I want) but when I add another div it looks like the second picture. I just want the text in the middle en the div under the first div.

This is my code

```
<div id="container">

<div id="over_asero">
    <p id="titel_text"> </p>

    <p id="sub_text"></p>

    <p id="sub_text"></p>
</div>

<div id="veiligheid">
    <p id="titel_text"> </p>

    <p id="sub_text"></p>

    <p id="sub_text"></p>
</div>
```

```
#container
{
position: relative;
width: 1140px;
height: 1500px;
margin: auto;
background-color: red;
}

#over_asero
{
position: relative;
width: 1140px;
height: 400px;
top: 150px;
z-index: 2;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#over_asero p
{
color: white;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#titel_text
{
font-size: 16px;
}
#sub_text
{
font-size: 12px;
}

#veiligheid
{
position: relative;
width: 1140px;
height: 400px;
top: 550px;
z-index: 2;
background-color: blue;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: You're reusing IDs on the same page...you can't do that. Use a class instead.

Comment: Oops, but it still doesn't work

Comment: do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uymgyeqy/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cover table-cell div's with parent div and add display table for it, as shown below

```
<div class="parent_div">
   <div id="over_asero"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent_div">
   <div id="veiligheid"></div>
</div>

.parent_div{
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Mark it as a answer, if it solves your issue.